# React context doesn't save data between pages

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, provider

I'm trying to implement a searches history in React. I add some searches to the history, but when I try to get them in another page, history array is Empty. Provider code is this:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const HistoryContext = React.createContext();
const AddSearchContext = React.createContext();
const ClearHistoryContext = React.createContext();

export function useHistoryContext(){
    //return useContext(HistoryContext);
    return useContext(HistoryContext);
}

export function useAddSearchContext(){
    return useContext(AddSearchContext);
}

export function useClearHistoryContext(){
    return useContext(ClearHistoryContext);
}

export function HistoryProvider(props){

    const [history, setHistory] = useState([]);

    function addSearch(search){
        setHistory(prevHistory => [...prevHistory, search]);
        console.log(history);
    }

    function clearHistory(){
        setHistory([]);
    }

    return (
        <HistoryContext.Provider value={history}>
            <AddSearchContext.Provider value={addSearch}>
                <ClearHistoryContext.Provider value={clearHistory}>
                    {props.children}
                </ClearHistoryContext.Provider>
            </AddSearchContext.Provider>
        </HistoryContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

Code where I add searches to the history is this:

```
const CityPage = () => {

    const addSearch = useAddSearchContext();
    const [zip, setZip] = useState(values.defaultzip);

    useEffect(() => {
        //...
        addSearch(zip); //add the zip to the history
        //...
    }, []);
    
    const handleOnClick = async () => {
        const zipValue = document.getElementById("input_zip").value;
        setZip(zipValue);
    };

    const content = (<>
        <div id="search_div">
            <input type="text" id="input_zip"/>
            <button id="search_button" onClick={handleOnClick}>Search</button>
        </div>
        </>
    );

    return (
        <MainLayout id="politicInfo">
            {content}
        </MainLayout>
    );
}

export default CityPage;
```

And code where I try to get it is:

```
import React from "react";
import MainLayout from "../MainLayout/MainLayout";
import { HistoryProvider, useHistoryContext } from "../../providers/HistoryProvider";

const HistoryPage = () => {

    const history = useHistoryContext();
    //console.log(history);

    return (
        <MainLayout>
            <h1>Contenido</h1>
        </MainLayout>
    );
}

export default HistoryPage;
```

App.js code is this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider } from './providers/ThemeProvider';
import { HistoryProvider } from './providers/HistoryProvider';
import './App.css';
import { LangProvider } from './providers/LangProvider';
import { AppRouter } from './AppRouter';

function App() {
  return (
    <HistoryProvider>
      <LangProvider>
        <ThemeProvider>
          <AppRouter />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </LangProvider>
    </HistoryProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`console.log` at HistoryProvider `addSearch` method shows the history array with the searches I've introduced, but `console.log` ubicated at HistoryPage show an empty array.

The other two providers work correctly.

MainLayout is simply a layout with a header and a body.

Sorry if it's an obvious mistake, I'm getting started in React.Thanks in advance.